# Datastudio : How to extract value inside HTML format using Presto (MySQL)

Tags: html, sql

I am looking to extract the value inside any HTML format (e.g.,  value ).

Here's is the example of HTML:
`<payment><no_code>88888</no_code><signature>fbf2c1e</signature><customer_no>4150</customer_no><amount>80</amount><admin>7</admin><total>87</total><transaction_code>0000894</transaction_code></payment>`

The output I am trying to fetch is the value inside the admin, which is **7**.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `REGEXP_EXTRACT()` here:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(html_string, '<admin>(.*?)</admin>', 1) AS admin
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: [do not parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1067003). You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML. The use of regex will not allow you to consume HTML. Regular expressions are a tool that is insufficiently sophisticated to understand the constructs employed by HTML. HTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be parsed by regular expressions. Regex queries are not equipped to break down HTML into its meaningful parts.

Comment: Thank you for you guys help. This one actually works. Since ExtractValue is not register in Presto

Answer (score -1):

use [ExtractValue](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) xpath, eg

```
SELECT ExtractValue(
'<payment><no_code>88888</no_code><signature>fbf2c1e</signature><customer_no>4150</customer_no><amount>80</amount><admin>7</admin><total>87</total><transaction_code>0000894</transaction_code></payment>',
 '/payment/admin'
)
```

=> 7

Comment: Do not parse HTML with regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this answer is parsing HTML with [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), not regex. XPath is literally designed to traverse XML.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if you're unfamiliar with XPaths, you can think of XPath as an alternative to CSS selectors. (and at least MySQL supports XPath but not CSS selectors)